# Get realtime photo updates of a tag from instagram

Tags: php, json, instagram, instagram-api

I am using Instagram realtime API for getting recent photos of a tag.
I am able to subscribe and it returns me the following data :

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    },
    "data": {
        "object": "tag",
        "object_id": "india",
        "aspect": "media",
        "callback_url": "http://test.com/myapp/callback.php",
        "type": "subscription",
        "id": "18436080"
    }
}
```

No data being sent when user uploads a new photo.
Here is my callback url code:

```html
<?php
$challenge = $_GET['hub_challenge'];    
if($challenge) {
      echo $challenge;
} else {
      sleep(2);

      $myString = file_get_contents('php://input');

      $jsonArray = json_decode($myString);
    var_dump($jsonArray);
    }
?>
```

How to debug whether call has come to my callback url or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check is `X-Hub-Signature` header with signature exists by

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_HUB_SIGNATURE']
```

This will be a SHA-1-signed hexadecimal digest, using your client secret as a key and the payload as the message.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove that call to

```
sleep(2);
```

It will timeout the post request, the documentation sais it here:

> Also, you should acknowledge the POST within a 2 second timeout--if you need to do more processing of the received information, you can do so in an asynchronous task.

Second of all, the name of the challenge variableis hub.challenge and not hub_challenge, check that out too.

Comment: PHP translates the dots (.) to underscores (_), so his parameter name is correct.